# CAS communicating with an external user store via REST

Tags: authentication, rest, single-sign-on, cas

Basically we are trying to implement CAS as an SSO solution in our org. All our user profiles are stored in a custom userstore that exposes certain REST APIs for fetching this info. What I want to know is whether I can use CAS here? Basically instead of querying a DB or an LDAP server CAS would just query this custom userstore via REST. Does CAS provide such a functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can. CAS by default does not provide this functionality. However, you can leverage the existing API to design & develop a custom authN handler that talks to the custom store through the REST API.

See the deployerConfigContext.xml file to review how authN handlers are defined and placed.

Also, if you do design the custom handler, please try and contribute that back to the community/codebase through a pull request on Github and discuss the details on either @cas-dev or @cas-user. There could be a possibility of merging the changes to the codebase to accommodate future similar requests.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently coding the handler. Will incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: That's great. If you run into any road blocks, be sure post ur questions to the list :)